# How To Use More Than One Condition in CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to use following conditions in one CASE how can i do that

```
((LTRIM(RTRIM(AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPPapCode)) = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@PapCode)))) AND
(DATEDIFF(DAY,(CONVERT(date,@PubDate,111)),(CONVERT(date,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,111)))) > (AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPAddNoOfDates)
AND
(LTRIM(RTRIM(AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPSysOperator))) != (LTRIM(RTRIM(@UserName))))
```

I try following way but I got Error

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN ((LTRIM(RTRIM(AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPPapCode)) = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@PapCode))))
          AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, (CONVERT(date, @PubDate, 111)), (CONVERT(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 111)))) > (AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPAddNoOfDates)
          AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPSysOperator))) != (LTRIM(RTRIM(@UserName))))
          IS NULL THEN 1

   AS ErrorTag;
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: You didn't close the `case` expression. Add `end` between `then 1` and `AS ErrorTag`.

Comment: Zohar Peled, yes I got it.

Comment: What's with the random `IS NULL` too?

Comment: Zohar Peled But error rise Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPPapCode" could not be bound.

Comment: Dear All - Actually I want to trigger error if three condition fulfilled. if three condition failed i want to trigger ok.

Comment: The multi-part identifier could not be bound means you are attempting to reference a wrong identifier. It could be as simple as a typo on the column or table name, it could be that you are attempting to use a column from one table but accidentally written another table, or you are using the wrong alias. Without seeing the entire select statement (and preferably the DDL of the table(s) involved, that's the most I can tell you about it.

Comment: Also, please consider using aliases! `AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication.AAADPPapCode` is an awful thing to read. `AAADP.AAADPPapCode` would be a lot easier.

Comment: ... Or just use the column name since it's clearly containing the initials of the table name - so just `AAADPPapCode` should be fine...

Comment: How can I use more that one conditions (combinations) in WHEN ?

Comment: `CASE WHEN [Column1] = 1 AND [Column2] IS NOT NULL AND [Column3] = 'Test' THEN 'All true' WHEN [Column1] = 2 THEN 'Just 1' ELSE 'Nothing' END` @Mark

Comment: Dear Larnu , Yes I try that, but I got MSG 4104, Level 16 State 1 Error. I'm using Table Name Also. Please see my initial question.

Comment: Show us your *new* attempt. The SQL you initally posted has at least 2 syntax errors (which myself and @ZoharPeled have highlighted to you).

Comment: Also, when posting an error, it's far more helpful to post the error message, not the state and level.

Comment: Its too long to post. I'll Post as a new question

Comment: If your `CASE` expression is too long, you have a much larger problem...

Answer (score 0):

your "case" didn't close "end" type the "end" before AS ErrorTag.