# How to Use More than One conditions in WHEN in CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to use multiple conditions in WHEN CASE.

I'm getting the following error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>
> The multi-part identifier "TableName.AAADPAddNoOfDates" could not be bound

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN ((LTRIM(RTRIM(TableName.AAADPPapCode)) = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@PapCode))))
      AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, (CONVERT(date, @PubDate, 111)), (CONVERT(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 111)))) > (TableName.AAADPAddNoOfDates)
      AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(TableName.AAADPSysOperator))) != (LTRIM(RTRIM(@UserName)))) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END AS ErrorTag;
```

Comment: There's no `FROM` in your statement, how do you expect any of those columns to be  bound?

Comment: Also, duplicate of [How To Use More Than One Condition in CASE Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490473/how-to-use-more-than-one-condition-in-case-statement)

Comment: how to use FROM with case

Comment: The error indicates that sql server was not able to find one of the columns and/or tables.  Can you post your full query? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples for examples of how to use select.

Comment: Dear Kami, Full query In above. My Table Name is AdvertisementAuthorityAfterDateOfPublication its too long that why i'm use TableName

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Use More Than One Condition in CASE Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490473/how-to-use-more-than-one-condition-in-case-statement)

Comment: I solve problem buy using EXISTS Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` statement looks fine but you are missing a `FROM` clause specifying the tables you are selecting from.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the table you need to retrieve the out put from.

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN ((LTRIM(RTRIM(TableName.AAADPPapCode)) = (LTRIM(RTRIM(@PapCode))))
  AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, (CONVERT(date, @PubDate, 111)), (CONVERT(date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
111)))) > (TableName.AAADPAddNoOfDates)
  AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(TableName.AAADPSysOperator))) != (LTRIM(RTRIM(@UserName)))) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS ErrorTag
FROM TableName;
```